# can't get how to transform square edge to the sphere

Tags: openscad

[image]

Is it possible with openscad built-in tools/commands smoothing square edge into the sphere? Whatever I try with cylinders the problem with 90 degrees shape remains re-appearing in another location. Looked through the documentation, did not find usable case. Searched internet with the same results.

This seems can't be achieved using circular or elliptic surfaces, some advanced transformation is needed.

**Solution:** there's a way using standard openSCAD 3D elements - intersection of two cylinders. Resulting surface is not ideally smooth, but at least there're no sharp corners.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Play around with HULL.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions :

```
$fn = 256;



module interpolation1($fn = $fn){
    
    points = [
    for(u = [0 : $fn]) each [
        [cos(u * 90 / $fn), 0, sin(u * 90 / $fn)], 
        for(v = [0 : $fn - 2])
        [
        (cos(v * 90 / ($fn - 2)) - 1) * cos(u * 90 / $fn) * (1 - cos(u * 180 / $fn)) / 2 + cos(u * 90 / $fn), 
        (sin(v * 90 / ($fn - 2)) - 1) * cos(u * 90 / $fn) * (1 - cos(u * 180 / $fn)) / 2 + cos(u * 90 / $fn), 
        sin(u * 90 / $fn)
        ], 
        [0, cos(u * 90 / $fn), sin(u * 90 / $fn)]
    ], 
    [0, 0, 0]
    ];
    
    faces = [
        for(u = [0 : $fn - 1])for(v = [0 : $fn - 1])[(v + 1) + u * ($fn + 1), v + u * ($fn + 1), v + (u + 1) * ($fn + 1), (v + 1) + (u + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(u = [$fn : -1 : 0]) u * ($fn + 1), ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(u = [0 : $fn]) (u + 1) * ($fn + 1) - 1, ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1), 0, 1, $fn]
    ];
    
    polyhedron(points, faces);
    
    

}

module interpolation2($fn = $fn){
    
    points = [
    for(u = [0 : $fn]) each [
        for(v = [0 : $fn]) let(n = u / $fn, r = (n == 0 ? min(1 / cos(v * 90 / $fn), 1 / sin(v * 90 / $fn)) : cos(u * 90 / $fn) * pow(pow(cos(v * 90 / $fn), 2 / n) + pow(sin(v * 90 / $fn), 2 / n), -n / 2)))
        [
        r * cos(v * 90 / $fn), 
        r * sin(v * 90 / $fn), 
        sin(u * 90 / $fn)
        ]
    ], 
    [0, 0, 0]
    ];
    
    faces = [
        for(u = [0 : $fn - 1])for(v = [0 : $fn - 1])[(v + 1) + u * ($fn + 1), v + u * ($fn + 1), v + (u + 1) * ($fn + 1), (v + 1) + (u + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(u = [$fn : -1 : 0]) u * ($fn + 1), ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(u = [0 : $fn]) (u + 1) * ($fn + 1) - 1, ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(v = [0 : $fn]) v, ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)]
    ];
    
    polyhedron(points, faces);
    
    

}
interpolation2();
```

In my opinion, the first one is cleaner but the fact that the second is Cinf continuous makes it better.

EDIT: here is a better version of the second solution (the vertices repartition is better):

```
module interpolation3($fn = $fn){
    
    points = [
    for(u = [0 : $fn]) each [
        for(v = [0 : $fn]) let(
            m = u / $fn, 
            n = 45 * ((2 * v / $fn - 1) * pow(abs(2 * v / $fn - 1), 1 / sqrt(m) - 1) + 1), 
            r = (m == 0 ? min(1 / cos(n), 1 / sin(n)) : cos(u * 90 / $fn) * pow(pow(cos(n), 2 / m) + pow(sin(n), 2 / m), -m / 2))
        )
        [
        r * cos(n), 
        r * sin(n), 
        sin(m * 90)
        ]
    ], 
    [0, 0, 0]
    ];
    
    faces = [
        for(u = [0 : $fn - 1])for(v = [0 : $fn - 1])[(v + 1) + u * ($fn + 1), v + u * ($fn + 1), v + (u + 1) * ($fn + 1), (v + 1) + (u + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(u = [$fn : -1 : 0]) u * ($fn + 1), ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(u = [0 : $fn]) (u + 1) * ($fn + 1) - 1, ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)], 
        [for(v = [0 : $fn]) v, ($fn + 1) * ($fn + 1)]
    ];
    
    polyhedron(points, faces);
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful function in openSCAD named *minkowski*.

Put simply, it performs the union of one shape, with a second shape placed at every point inside of the first shape.

So to round the corners of a sharp edged rectangular model, you simply perform a Minkowski sum between the model and a sphere with a suitable radius/diameter, adjusting for the extra volume added by placing a sphere at every point on the edges.

[image: hard edged cuboid]

```
edgeDiam=3;
minkowski()
{
 union(){ 
     cube([15,15,30]-[edgeDiam,edgeDiam,edgeDiam],center=true);
     rotate([90,0,0])cube([10,10,30]-[edgeDiam,edgeDiam,edgeDiam],center=true);
 };
 sphere(d=edgeDiam,$fn=100);
 };
```

[image: minkowski rounded cuboid]